# Firefox что возвращает DOMMouseScr

Tags: прокрутка, javascript

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, что возвращает DOMMouseScr в firefox?
есть код.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function scrolling(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {  
        alert('true');
    }
    else { 
        alert('false');
    }
});
```

В лисице всё время возвращается false. Чему равен скролл вниз-вверх в нём?

Comment: @Deonis иногда мне кажется, что нужно добавить запрет редактирования, если пост уже редактируется.

Comment: @lampa, согласен. Неувязочки случаются.

Answer (score 1):

```
var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
```